# Find if a JSON Value contains certain text

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I'm not sure if this is possible, because I have not found anything on this..
I am going through a JSON object..

```
{"name": "zack",
 "message": "hello",
 "time": "US 15:00:00"},

{"name": "zack",
 "message": "hello",
 "time": "US 00:00:00"}
```

Is there a way I can select the time property that contains just the "15:00:00" part?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you be a little bit more clear about what you mean? What do you mean by select?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand if you parse your JSON you have an array of object. So you can make use of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function and filter out those elements that don't match the criteria you pass in filter function:

```js
var parsedJson = [{"name": "zack",
 "message": "hello",
 "time": "US 15:00:00"},{"name": "zack",
 "message": "hello",
 "time": "US 00:00:00"}];
 
 var result = parsedJson.filter(item=>item.time === "US 15:00:00");
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 15:00:00"
}, {
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 00:00:00"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var time = (arr[i].time.split('US '))[1];
    console.log(time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` function to filter the array, and can use `indexOf` to check whether `time` field contains `15:00:00` or not.

E.g:

```
var json = [{
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 15:00:00"
  },

  {
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 00:00:00"
  }
];


 var resultObj = json.filter(item=>item.time.indexOf("15:00:00") !== -1);
 console.log(resultObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array#filter function. It will return a new array with matched element. If the length of new array is 0 then no match was found

```js
var myJson = [{
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 15:00:00"
  },

  {
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 00:00:00"
  }
]

var m = myJson.filter(function(item) {
  return item.time === "US 15:00:00"

})

console.log(m)
```

[**findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) can also be used to find if it contains the value. If the value is -1 it mean the json array does not contain any object that match the criteria

```js
var myJson = [{
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 15:00:00"
  },

  {
    "name": "zack",
    "message": "hello",
    "time": "US 00:00:00"
  }
]

var m = myJson.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item.time === "US 15:00:00"

});
console.log(m)
```

Comment: The author wanted to filter like mysql LIKE operator while your answer contain  ===